# Create SSIS package with Dynamic Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

We have a new requirement to create an SSIS package. when package got executed it should copy certain table data into a excel file.

Tablename, excel file path, excel file name is dynamic (it is based on the  user input).
I am new to SSIS, and I have worked only with static values. How to implement the above scenario in SSIS?

Comment: From where the user inputs are coming (application, SSMS, schedule, etc.)?

Comment: Are the Excel file structures, and the Table structures going to be exactly the same every time?

Comment: @Aka Guymelef ,  It come from the Application and We thought to pass the inputs as parameter to a stored procedure.

Comment: @Raj More, Table Structure Obviously different and excel strucure is depend on the table stucture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easy in SSIS, because you need a Data Conversion component between your table source and your Excel destination. That Data Conversion component must have different columns every time you have a query with different output columns.

On the web I found some solutions, but none of them worked for me. So I wrote my own solution, that basically consists of the following steps:

- Get the contents of an SQL script file (in that file you can put a select query).
- Create a temporary table from the script code (for determining the structure of the output).
- Generate and execute a script for creating the Excel worksheet.
- Dynamically generate a temporary package for executing the SQL script with an Excel file as output.
- Execute and drop the dynamic package.

Currently I am writing an article on [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com) to share what I have developed. However, it may take a while until it is finshed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I got struck in 3 and 4th points. Can u elaborate littile more on those?

Comment: You're welcome. I will do that in my article on codeproject. It requires a lot of explanation... But in short: create a CREATE TABLE script for Excel. An example can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301542/Creating-Excel-File-and-ExcelSheets-dynamically-fr. Code for generating a dynamic package can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/01/02/api-sample-data-conversion.aspx.

Comment: kindly give a notification once you done with the article. let me try myself

Comment: @user5359841: Here is the article on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037650/Export-output-of-SQL-Server-script-to-Excel-SSIS.

Comment: You're welcom bmsqldev!